# How to retrieve values from a javascript object using a variable's contents as the property?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON, I am trying to retrieve values by substituting variables as below.

```
var model = {
    regression : {
        regUtils : {
            subIDs : {
                B00099999823 : {
                    "a" : "b",
                    "c" : "d"               
            }
        }
    }
};



var vals = "B00099999823";
alert(model.regression.regUtils.subIDs.vals.a); // error returned : Object doesn't support this property or method

alert(model.regression.regUtils.subIDs.B00099999823.a); //alerts b
```

How can I substitute a variable in place of a key or object.
thanks.

Comment: `regression.regUtils.subIDs[vals].a`

Comment: What you have is a **JavaScript object**, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access with a variable contents like this:

```
var vals = "B00099999823";
alert(model.regression.regUtils.subIDs[vals].a;
```

You can use `[]` to access an object by using a variables contents.  It would be the same as this:

```
model.regression.regUtils.subIDs['B00099999823'].a
```